# Updating NumericUpDown value according to another NumericUpDown control

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

Guys if i have 2 numeric updown in my XAML like this

```
<Input:SfNumericUpDown Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,10,0"  Value="{Binding CompoundQty}" ValueChanged="SfNumericUpDown_ValueChanged"/>
<Input:SfNumericUpDown Grid.Column="4" Margin="10,0,10,0" Value="{Binding ResultQty}" Tag="{Binding ItemID}" />
```

I want the second numericupdown value is changed according to first numericupdown value.
i try to put this in Code behind.

```
private void SfNumericUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Controls.Input.ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var numCompoundQty = (SfNumericUpDown)sender;
        foreach(var row in _entityEdited.ListCompoundDisplay)
        {
            if(row.ItemID == Convert.ToInt32(numCompoundQty.Tag))
            {
                row.CompoundQty = Convert.ToDecimal(numCompoundQty.Value);
                row.ResultQty = Convert.ToDecimal(numDispenseQty.Value) * row.CompoundQty;
                break;
            }
        }



    }
```

but it doesnt work, can you guys help me what is the problem?

Comment: Are you raising the proper notifypropertychanged of the properties?

Comment: Im not using any notifypropertychanged function sir...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have a problem here, because you're trying to reference an element called "numDispenseQty", which you don't have access to (assuming it is inside a DataTemplate).  Instead of handling the "value changed" event, you should be using a two-way binding to the view-model:

```
<Input:SfNumericUpDown Value="{Binding CompoundQty,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Now put the update logic inside the setter for the "CompoundQty" property, eg:

```
public double CompoundQty
{
    get { return _compoundQty; }
    set
    { 
        _compoundQty = value;
        UpdateResultQty();
        RaisePropertyChanged("CompoundQty");
    }
}

private void UpdateResultQty()
{
    ResultQty = DispenseQty * CompoundQty;
}
```

Note that (as @sslazio1900 notes) your view-model class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever a property changes (that is how the view knows to update itself).

Answer (score 2):

Try to raise NotifiyPropertyChanged events on both properties.

If not, Binding Engine is unable to detect a value change, than you'll never get your values updated.